# Error: Illegal Instruction. Mips cross-compiler

Tags: c, mips

I compile simple program on Linux x64 with Mips cross-compiller and upload it on my router with *scp*. When i run this program, i have error: *Illegal instruction* .

**My program:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  printf("Hello, world!");
  return 0;
}
```

**/proc/cpuinfo** of my mips-box:

```
system type         : Atheros AR9330 rev 1
machine             : TP-LINK TL-WR741ND v4
processor           : 0
cpu model           : MIPS 24Kc V7.4
isa                 : mips1 mips2 mips32r1 mips32r2
ASEs implemented    : mips16
```

**Compile:**

```
mips-linux-gnu-gcc -static -march=24kc -o hello hello.c
```

**Upload:**

```
scp hello root@192.168.1.1:/tmp
```

**Run:**

```
root@OpenWrt:/tmp# ./hello
Illegal instruction
```

Comment: I *highly* doubt the standard C libraries (here, `stdio.h`) can be used in this case.

Comment: I try to compile this program without any libs. Only **int main(void){}**. The result is exactly the same.@SusmitAgrawal

Comment: Try using the `-ffreestanding` flag.

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solved.

I use another toolchain. Link: https://www.mips.com/develop/tools/codescape-mips-sdk/download-codescape-mips-sdk-essentials/.

For **MIPS Classic Legacy CPU IP Cores: 4k, M4k, M14k, 24k, 34k, 74k, 1004k, 1074k** with the same compile command.